# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2

Tags: pip, pycharm, opencv, python

Obviously, I'm new to these problems, but I have a weird problem:

I'm using MacOS and I'm using Mac Terminal.
I installed `opencv` and even I saw its version and I was able to import `cv2`, but I wonder why I'm not able to install `cv2` in `pycharm`?

I tried, but `pycharm` gives me this error:

> (Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions:
>   No matching distribution found for cv2)

and it also says

> you are using pip version 10.0.1 however version 18.0 is available

It's really ridiculous, because I updated `pip` to version 18, but apparently `pycharm` doesn't understand...

Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

Comment: Haven't you read this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: @colidyre didn't work for me

Comment: I recommend using a virtual environment (create it in PyCharm for your project) and then also install your package for this seperate interpreter via PyCharm, see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-interpreters.html

Answer (score 12):

try installing opencv-python instead of cv2, I hope it works.